# Azure web app deployment default document index.php internal service error

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

My goal is to get index.php as my default document working, but I get the error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

At first I thought it could be the configuration path mapping, which I have set the virtual path / to map to \site\public with type Application.

However, when I put a test file index.html in my public folder with a simple `<p> hello world</p>`, running the app worked fine.

Why wouldn't the equivalent index.php work?

Comment: It seems your servers PHP setup is not correct, something is wrong with PHP. May be adding monitoring to your app, so you will be able to see any error on startup

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha thank you for pointing me towards that. I took a hard look at my web.config file, and I saw the PHP version was incorrect.

Comment: Have the problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done this already so, set the default document (index.php) your WebApps>>  Under Application Setting blade on the Azure Portal.
“Default document and map the path “Virtual applications and directories”.

On Linux, the container runs Apache, you can rewrite the URL to public/index.php with a single .htaccess file in our root directory.
Also, ensure that Rewrite rules are appropriate to map URLs to public/index.php file.

Furthermore, the default PHP image for App Service uses Apache, and it doesn't let you customize the site root for your app. To work around this limitation, add an .htaccess file to your repository root with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The [document](http://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-php#change-site-root) -If you would rather not use .htaccess rewrite, you can deploy your Laravel application with a custom Docker image instead.